# Divisors of elliptic curves (Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne, Chap. IV: Curves on page 319 I found this proof:

> **Proposition 4.6.** Let $X$ be an elliptic curve over $k$, with char $k \neq 2$, and let
>   $P_0  \in X$ be a given point. Then there is a closed immersion $X \to \mathbb{P}^2$ such
>   that the image is the curve

$$y^2 = x(x - 1)(x - \lambda)$$

> for some $\lambda \in k$, and the point $P_0$ goes to the point at infinity $(0,1,0)$ on the
>   $y$-axis. Furthermore, this $\lambda$ is the same as the $\lambda$ defined earlier, up to an
>   element of $\Sigma_3$ as in (4.5).
>
> **PROOF.** We embed $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ by the linear system $\vert 3P_0 \vert $, which gives a closed
>   immersion (3.3.3). We choose our coordinates as follows. Think of the
>   vector spaces $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(n P_0 ))$ as contained in each other,

\begin{equation}
 k =  H^0(\mathcal{O}_X) \subset H^0(\mathcal{O}_X( P_0 )) \subset H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(2 P_0 )) \subset...   \tag{1}\label{eq:0105star}
  \end{equation}

> By Riemann-Roch, we have

$$\dim_k H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(n P_0 ))=n $$

> for $n >0$. Choose...

Q: how the chain $$
k =  H^0(\mathcal{O}_X) \subset H^0(\mathcal{O}_X( P_0 )) \subset H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(2 P_0 )) \subset... $$

is concretely constructed in the proof? to obtain an inclusion $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X( k P_0 )) \subset H^0(\mathcal{O}_X((k+1) P_0 ))$ we need an inclusion of $\mathcal{O}_X$-sheaves $\mathcal{O}(k P_0) \subset \mathcal{O}((k+1) P_0)$ but since $kP_0$ is nothing but a closed subscheme of $(k+1)P_0$. therefore wo have only a surjective map $(k+1)P_0 \to kP_0$ in "wrong" direction. consequently I don't know why the chain (1) make any sense.

Comment: Presumably $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(\ell P_0))$ consists of those functions in $\mathcal{O}_X$ that a pole of order at most $\ell$ at $P_0$, and no other poles. This gives us the prescribed inclusions.

Comment: I suppose you working with this definition: let $X$ be a normal projective curve over field $k$. let $Z=\sum_{x \text{ closed}} n_x [x]$ be a $0$-cycle on $X$ and $D \in Div(X)$ a Cartier divisor such that $[D]=Z$. then

$$H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D))=\{f\in K(X)^*: \mbox{mult}_x(f)+n_x\geq 0\}\cup \{0\}$$

Comment: this gives obviously the inclusion $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X( \ell P_0 )) \subset H^0(\mathcal{O}_X((\ell+1) P_0 )$ I was looking for. one remark: do you know if there exist an inclusion of $\mathcal{O}_X$-sheaves $\mathcal{O}_X(\ell P_0) \subset \mathcal{O}_X((\ell +1) P_0)$ which naturally induce the inclusion $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X( \ell P_0 )) \subset H^0(\mathcal{O}_X((\ell+1) P_0 )$ or does this inclusion only work only on level of global sections?

Comment: You can tensor the injection $\mathcal{O}_X(-P_0) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ by $\mathcal{O}_X((l+1)P_0)$